# calling a function from PL/SQL in a select statement in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is my PL/SQL function portion. I am trying to use the function in a select statement. for example we can write a query like `select count(column_name) from table_name`. Here count is a function. I want to use my own functions like this. I've tried differently (using the function outside the PL/SQL function, inside the PL/SQL function). But it throws an error `PLS-00231:function 'GET_ANNUAL_COMP' may not be used in SQL` when used inside PL/SQL function and throws `ORA-00904 invalid identifier` when when used outside the PL/SQL function.

I'm using oracle 11g.

```
declare
em_sal number(20);
em_comm employees.commission_pct%type; 
annual_salary number(10,4);

function get_annual_comp(sal in number, comm in number)
return number is
begin
return (sal*12 + comm*12);
end;
begin
select salary into em_sal from employees where employee_id=149;
select commission_pct into em_comm from employees where employee_id=149;

annual_salary := get_annual_comp(em_sal,em_comm);

dbms_output.put_line('total salary '|| annual_salary);

select get_annual_comp(salary,commission_pct) from employees where department_id=90;
end;
/
```

Comment: To be Used with `SQL`, the function has be compiled as an _DB Object_ using `CREATE OR REPLACE ...` So the error says in `PL/SQL` exactly, as it sees a scope in it's block.. Where as when we try from outside, it don't even recognise and hence `invalid identifier`. So you have to create the function _globally_ , when you want it with `SQL`.

Comment: Do you really need to have this function in the PL/SQL anonymous block?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar btw, in 12c it is no longer a requirement, you can inline plsql functions in sql

Comment: Oh cool, Thanks for your info! @beherenow .I haven't got chance to explore 12c!!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-sep/o53plsql-1999801.html

Comment: thanks Maheswaran. Gave me a clue that worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Compile the function in an appropriate schema (sames schema that will be running anonymous block) as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_ANNUAL_COMP(
    sal  IN NUMBER,
    comm IN NUMBER)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN (sal*12 + comm*12);
END;
```

With same schema as the function, run the anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  em_sal NUMBER(20);
  em_comm employees.commission_pct%type;
  annual_salary NUMBER(10,4);
BEGIN
  SELECT salary INTO em_sal FROM employees WHERE employee_id=149;
  SELECT commission_pct INTO em_comm FROM employees WHERE employee_id=149;
  annual_salary := get_annual_comp(em_sal,em_comm);
  dbms_output.put_line('total salary '|| annual_salary);
  SELECT SUM(get_annual_comp(salary,commission_pct)) into annual_salary
  FROM employees
  WHERE department_id=90;
  dbms_output.put_line('department annual salary '|| annual_salary);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the function globally. Also ensure that the function is created in same schema also the logged in user has necessary privileges in the schema.